# Building Dashboard within existing website

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, themes, angular-ui-bootstrap

*I'm trying to include a dashboard in my existing website. I have seen multiple themes and github projects but still not convinced with the right framework/theme to go for my project. I can use themes but that gives me lesser flexibility to change things. At same time, I want to build my dashboard faster.*

Can anyone out here please help me how to get this done ?

I found following links on searching through internet. But a bit confused.

https://github.com/rdash/rdash-angular

https://github.com/sdorra/angular-dashboard-framework

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/

There are many more I'm sure....

**Open questions:**

```
1. Can anyone give me suggestions about how exactly how can I go with
development to make things faster ?

2. Is there any existing framework for same which can help me in rapid development ?

3. If not, then are there any small node.js packages, then can accomplish smaller tasks for me ?

4. Are there any good tutorials/blogs to go about building basic dashboard? Adding/Removing features can be done later.
```

Your inputs are welcome.

Thanks